# Question about proof regarding span

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I was working through Linear Algebra Done Right and had a question about whether a proof I gave for a question is valid or not. I've seen solutions to this question online but I wanted to see if this method worked.

Prove that if $(v_1,...,v_n)$ spans $V$, then so does the list 
$(v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,...,v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n)$.

My attempt:

Let $L$ denote $(v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,...,v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n)$ and $L_k$ be the $k$'th element of $L$.

Note that: $$v_k  = \sum_{i=k}^{n} L_i$$

Let $U$ denote the vector space spanned by $(v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,...,v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n)$.

From the sum above we can see that $v_1,...v_n\in U$. Since $U$ is a vector space every linear combination of its elements is in $U$. It follows that $V\subseteq U$, and thus $L$ spans $V$.

Does this method work or are there any tips?

Comment: Yep that works.

Comment: Nice proof, Jack.